# Making Post request in a flask template for loop

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a post request in a flask template for loop where I am passing the id from each of the element in the for loop back to the endpoint.
I want to be able to receive the id of the element I clicked from the frontend. The click work but a wrong element (not the id that I clicked) is being sent to the endpoint.

```
{% for data in profile %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                <td>{{data.full_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.given_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.created_at | format_datetime('full')}}</td>
                <td>
                  <form method="post" id="is_admin">
                    <input hidden name="profile_id" value="{{data.id}}" />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="toogle_off" id="{{data.id}}"
                    onchange="document.getElementById('is_admin').submit()" {{
                    "checked" if data.is_admin == True }} /> {{data.is_admin}}
                  </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
```

When I click any of the profile, it I got a ID. it returns a particular element all the time. The profile is from a database query.

I have tried setting the id for the input submitting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create multiple forms with the same id: `id="is_admin"` and with `getElementById('is_admin')` selector you submit only the first form every time. You need to create unique ids form the forms/selectors as well, e.g.:

```
{% for data in profile %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.email}}</td>
    <td>{{data.full_name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.given_name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.created_at | format_datetime('full')}}</td>
    <td>
      <form method="post" id="is_admin_form_{{data.id}}">
        <input hidden name="profile_id" value="{{data.id}}" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="toogle_off" id="{{data.id}}"
          onchange="document.getElementById('is_admin_form_{{data.id}}').submit()" {{
          "checked" if data.is_admin == True }} /> {{data.is_admin}}
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```